# Problems adding cURL to OAuth request engine support

Tags: php, curl, oauth, ubuntu-14.04, php-extension

I've recently been setting up a new environment for a web application I'm working on and I've run into this following issue that I cannot figure out.

Currently I have a docker-composer setup based off of https://hub.docker.com/r/ruslangetmansky/docker-apache-php/

Where I have my API, APP and DB running and need them to talk between each other.

During the initialisation of this, I'm currently doing the following command:

`command: bash -c 'apt-get update && apt-get -y install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl php5-oauth && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && composer install && /sbin/entrypoint.sh'`

I've even tried separating out the php5-oauth in-case we're running into a timing issue like so, but the same issue persists:

`command: bash -c 'apt-get update && apt-get -y install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl && apt-get -y install php5-oauth && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && composer install && /sbin/entrypoint.sh'`

As you can see, I've been trying everything to get `php5-oauth` built with cURL support,  however at the moment the current build ends up with only `php_streams` request engine support:
[image: oauth with no cURL support]
However it looks like cURL support is also built in:
[image: curl support also exists]
So currently when I boot my app+api, I can't talk between them due to no cURL support, as I've errors all over my application complaining of undefined constants such as the two following:

`Message: Use of undefined constant OAUTH_REQENGINE_CURL - assumed 'OAUTH_REQENGINE_CURL'`

and

`Message: OAuth::setRequestEngine() expects parameter 1 to be long, string given`

due to the lack of cURL support.

I also spotted similar questions around Stack Overflow, but nothing seems to mention what to do when these are installed and enabled but only 1 request engine is available.

Other research has led me to http://www.davidogilo.co.uk/technical/how-to-fix-oauth_reqengine_curl-is-undefined/ but my cURL default path has always been found succesfully.

Can anyone give me a hand here, or at least point out where i'm possibly going wrong? Cheers.

Comment: Please show output of `sudo pecl install oauth`

Comment: Mikhail, `php5-oauth`installs oauth 1.2.3 via pecl. So if I did `pecl install oauth` here it'll already be installed.

Comment: Could you reinstall oauth?

Comment: I've tried that by directly running the commands on the docker container, but no luck still, unfortunately. Same result.

Comment: If it is possible reinstall oauth and post output

Comment: the output of a pecl reinstall or a php5-oauth install?

Comment: pecl reinstallation (`sudo pecl install oauth`)

Comment: Just you mentioning that actually fixed it Mikhail. When I've got it installed via `php5-oauth` and then I uninstall with `pecl uninstall oauth` and then install with `pecl install oauth-1.2.3` it re-compiles and installs correctly (with cURL as a request engine). I've just added this to my command list and everything is working perfectly. Would you like to add it in as an answer and I'll accept it? Or I could just list what I did myself. Up to yourself. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall oauth with `sudo pecl install oauth` to compile it with cURL support