# Problems adding cURL to OAuth request engine CENTOS 7

Tags: curl, oauth, plesk, pecl, php-5.6

Very similar to [Problems adding cURL to OAuth request engine support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38397220/problems-adding-curl-to-oauth-request-engine-support)

Except the solutions listed don't work as this server is CENTOS 7 with Plesk Onyx.
The default install of Oauth to php 5.6 is very simple:

```
/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/pecl install oauth-1.2.3
extension=oauth.so (added to php.ini)
```

But the wrong request engine. 
[phpinfo shot of OAuth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hh7Ub.png)
I need Curl to be the request engine and not php-streams. Please help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**checking for cURL in default path... cURL not found**

Solved:

```
/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/pecl uninstall oauth-1.2.3 

yum install libcurl-devel.x86_64

/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/pecl install oauth-1.2.3
```