# PHP 7.1 oAuth extension with Request Engine Support using Curl - OAUTH_REQENGINE_CURL

Tags: curl, oauth, libcurl, pecl, php-7.1

I created a Docker image from ubuntu 18.04
I'm using php 7.1

The problem is I need to enable Request engine support using curl on the Oauth extension.

[image: Phpinfo oauth]
[image: Phpinfo curl]

The solution from this problem, [Problems adding cURL to OAuth request engine support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38397220/problems-adding-curl-to-oauth-request-engine-support)
did not solve my problem.
Steps taken:

- I've ran *PECL install oauth* and *PECL install oauth-2.0.3* to
  reinstall the oauth extention
- Restarted the apache *service apache2 restart* with no success.

I'll be happy to provide more information on request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encountered the same problem and I managed to completely resolve it only after reading the code of the PECL OAuth module.
Looks like that from Ubuntu 17.04 curl is located in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/curl` instead of `/usr/include/curl`, so OAuth doesn't find it and doesn't enable curl as a request engine.
So, as a temporary solution I symlinked the file.

Here below the commands I ran to enable the curl request engine:

```
# Uninstall oauth if already installed ('sudo pecl uninstall oauth')
sudo apt install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
cd /usr/include && sudo ln -s x86_64-linux-gnu/curl
sudo pecl install oauth
```

Answer (score 2):

Curl must be installed before installing oauth and `libpcre3-dev` is required. Below is an example snippet for the Dockerfile:

```
# Curl
RUN apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev

# OAuth
RUN apt-get install -y libpcre3-dev && pecl install oauth \
    && echo "extension=oauth.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-oauth.ini
```